# I am loading content via Ajax, but I need it to not load anything when my site loads

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm loading content into several divs with

ajax_loadContent

```
<div class="content"><div class="container" id="contents2"><!-- Empty div for dynamic content -->Loading content. please wait...</div><script type="text/javascript">ajax_loadContent('contents2','http://www.thewebsite.com/blank.php');</script></div>
```

Basically, I don't want to load anything until the user clicks on the links I have specified to load content into these instances, please help! Right now, I'm loading a blank file to show nothing in the div.

Comment: "I don't want to load anything until the user clicks on the links" - so then bind your function invocation for links onclick then?

Comment: Yup, right now it's an onclick event called from a link.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is being called inside the `<script>` tags, so it's going to run as soon as the javascript is loaded.

Using jQuery, run the function only when elements with the id "link_id" are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link_id").click(function() {
        ajax_loadContent('contents2','http://www.thewebsite.com/blank.php');
    });
});
```

or using a non jQuery method:

```
<a href="javascript:ajax_loadContent('contents2','http://www.thewebsite.com/blank.php')">clickme</a>
```

*or*

```
<a href="" onClick="ajax_loadContent('contents2','http://www.thewebsite.com/blank.php');return false;">click me</a>
```

Comment: why do you think he is using jquery?

Comment: do you mean non jquery? ;-) and why it's not at onclick="" ?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the reply, I'm not using jQuery unfortunately :( I should but this is a buddy's old site, I believe using http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=ajax-dynamic-content

Comment: to load content the page's already using 

<a href="#" onclick="ajax_loadContent('contents2','http://www.thepage.com');return false" />Load this into box</a>